# How to recreate the BETA.INV() function from Excel in R?

Tags: r, excel, distribution

I would like to recreate the BETA.INV() function from Excel in R. For example, BETA.INV(0.05,1,3,4,14)=4.1695. How to get the same in R?

Answer (score 3):

The main function to use to get the inverse of the beta distribution in R is the `qbeta` function. Normal beta distrributions are between 0 and 1. Excel allows you to specify different lower and upper bounds. In order to mimic that feature, we need to scale the returned value on the 0-1 scale to the lower-upper scale. Here's a function which does that

```
betainv <- function(p, alpha, beta, lower, upper) {
  qbeta(p, alpha, beta) * (upper-lower) + lower
}

betainv(0.05,1,3,4,14)
# [1] 4.169524
```